# Is Ingenuity a "spacecraft?"

Tags: spacecraft, terminology, ingenuity

NASA calls its helicopter on Mars a [spacecraft](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/358/grounded-first-flight-delay-due-to-inclement-weather-on-another-world/) (status update, 2022 Jan 19).  Why?

Sure, Ingenuity is off Earth and it's mobile.  But it can't toodle off to Phobos.  It's in the same category as rovers, hoppers, etc., which also can't travel through space, but only get *delivered* through space to a destination.

(Other status updates have called it a [rotorcraft](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/354/flight-19-new-year-same-ingenuity/); also called Perseverance a [spacecraft](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/350/flight-17-discovering-limits/)(!); mentioned [spacecraft on Mars](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/336/2800-rpm-spin-a-success-but-flight-14-delayed-to-post-conjunction/); and just once called it an [aircraft](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/316/aerial-scouting-of-raised-ridges-for-ingenuitys-flight-10/)).

Comment: Why not all three? The rotor-space-air-craft!

Comment: Well, it flies in a (medium) vacuum. ;)

Comment: It can't fly in a vacuum as other spacecrafts can do.

Comment: The internet has once again fulfilled its main purpose: an argument about definitions.

Answer (score 5):

The [definition of spacecraft](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spacecraft) is: a vehicle or device designed for travel or operation outside the Earth's atmosphere.

So yes, Ingenuity is a spacecraft.

Comment: A hundred years from now when a Mars colonist take's their scooter down the road to pick up a loaf of bread it will no longer be thought of as a spacecraft, but until that time I think that this is probably going to continue to be the prevailing terminology.

Comment: The [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spacecraft_ has a more restricted/specific definition: *A vehicle used for traveling in space.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft) lists Ingenuity as a rotocraft & a spacecraft as a"*vehicle or machine designed to fly in outer space*". ...

Comment: ... [Other definitions](https://www.wordnik.com/words/spacecraft) include: *A vehicle designed to be launched into space.*,  a vehicle capable of traveling in or into outer space; at present, all such vehicles are powered by rocket engine, A vehicle that travels through space, a craft capable of traveling in outer space; technically, a satellite around the sun.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's "For travel **or** operation" implies that it needn't even be able to move.  That casts the net wide enough to include the Apollo astronauts' shovels and rock collecting bags.